# ROracle installed but loading failure installing a depending package

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I'm working on a Windows Server x64 with R version 3.5.1 (see [sessionInfo for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRKmf.png)).

ROracle package version 1.3-1 is already installed (see [installed.packages details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE67s.png)) and works fine (see [ROracle call example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMO5t.png)).

I intend to install an internal developed R package which has the following dependencies declared in its 'DESCRIPTION' file : "*Depends: R (>= 3.1.0), DBI, ROracle*".

When I launch this internal package installation, I get the following error message (see [attached screenshot for full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4s6U.png)):

> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> Error : package 'ROracle' is not installed for 'arch = i386'
>
> Error: loading failed Execution halted
>
> *** arch - x64
>
> ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'

For information this package has already been installed on several computers without facing any error, the first trouble happens on this virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the installation you are running for your package is testing your package in a multiarch environment, which is therefore checking the dependencies in a multiarch environment. There would be 2 ways around this:

1. Install a 32-bit ROracle client in addition to the 64-bit, set the appropriate OCI_LIB32 environment variable, and re-install ROracle so it is aware of both architectures.
2. Add the `--no-multiarch` option to your install, so either `R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch` or `install.packages(...,configure.args = c("--no-multiarch"))`.